# xcodebuild error "clang: error: unknown argument: '-fYEScolor-diagnostics'"

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, xcodebuild, ios-ui-automation

When running xcodebuild for UIAutomation tests I'm getting a clang unknown argument error. There are plenty of solutions from similar issues how ever they don't work for me. Spicifically ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future does not solve the issue.

Here is the command I'm running:

```
xcodebuild -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace \
-scheme "myScheme" \
   -sdk iphonesimulator \
   -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=9.2,name=iPhone 6' \
   test
```

And the error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fYEScolor-diagnostics'
```

I'm running xcode 7.2.1 and OSX 10.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is to add the argument 
    `OTHER_CFLAGS="-Qunused-arguments"`
to the xcodebuild command, eg:

```
xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-Qunused-arguments"-workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace \
-scheme "myScheme" \
   -sdk iphonesimulator \
   -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=9.2,name=iPhone 6' \
   test
```